# Copy and paste text from within Adobe Digital Editions 4.5

Tags: adobe-reader

I am attempting to copy and paste `R` code from an ebook using `Adobe Digital Editions 4.5`.  At first I had no problem.  However, lately `ctrl-c` has stopped working to copy text.  A search of the internet has located a number of similar complaints, but no solution.

I wonder whether `Adobe` has placed a limit on how much text can be copied from an ebook.  The authors of the book clearly intend for the code to be used by readers and even provide an `R` package containing code from latter chapters.  However, I am working my way through the earlier chapters and this code does not appear to be in the package.

How can I copy computer code from an ebook using `Adobe Digital Editions 4.5`.  I am using a `Windows 7` machine and do not have the option to upgrade to a `Windows 10`.

Comment: Does the R book have a companion website? Code normally lives there

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with [Epubor Ultimate](https://www.filelem.com/product/epubor-ultimate). It coverts your drm protected pdf into normal pdf and you are able to work with it like usual.

Comment: It seems like that site is not working anymore.

Comment: @Cit5 link updated